# Using centos7 as base image for Jaeger

Tags: go, jaeger

I am trying to setup Jaeger using a CentOS base image instead of Alpine. The agent, collector, and Cassandra containers all work fine except for the query container.
The Jaeger repository is [here](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/tree/master/cmd).
After changing the base image to CentOS 7, commenting out the sections that apply to copying `ca-certificates.crt` and running `docker-compose`, I get the following nil pointer error message when tailing the query container

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

I ran the makefile with the necessary flags to compile the code in the app directory.
Has anyone ever setup Jaeger using CentOS as a base image?

Below is the full stack error from the container

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app.NewStaticAssetsHandler(0x0, 0x0, 0xe6cb85, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0000397a0, 0xc0000397b0, 0xc000137098)
    /Users/myusername/Go/src/github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app/static_handler.go:74 +0x5e
github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app.RegisterStaticHandler(0xc0000a7bd0, 0xc00009d080, 0xc0001eec80)
    /Users/myusername/Go/src/github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/app/static_handler.go:45 +0x74
main.main.func1(0xc0001746c0, 0xc000184f60, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/myusername/Go/src/github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/main.go:131 +0x14eb
github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc0001746c0, 0xc00008e0a0, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc0001746c0, 0xc00008e0a0)
    /Users/myusername/Go/src/github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:698 +0x47a
github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc0001746c0, 0x0, 0x4, 0xc00009cfc0)
    /Users/myusername/Go/src/github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:783 +0x2dc
github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0xc0001746c0, 0xc0001746c0, 0xc000137f28)
    /Users/myusername/Go/src/github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:736 +0x2b
main.main()
    /Users/myusername/Go/src/github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/cmd/query/main.go:172 +0x5a6
{"level":"info","ts":1539888666.5870771,"caller":"healthcheck/handler.go:99","msg":"Health Check server started","http-port":16687,"status":"unavailable"}
{"level":"info","ts":1539888666.6052766,"caller":"cassandra/factory.go:92","msg":"Cassandra archive storage configuration is empty, skipping"}
{"level":"info","ts":1539888666.6063912,"caller":"query/main.go:186","msg":"Archive storage not created","reason":"Archive storage not configured"}
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0xbe2b9e
```

Comment: Sounds like there is an error somewhere in the code, but the full error and the code generating it were not included in the question.

Comment: I have revised this to include the full error.

Comment: Bugs in third party software should be submitted to their issue trackers.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the static assets *not* being included in the binary. You can try that out by running the binary you compiled.

Instead of compiling on your own, a better approach would be to get the official binaries from the releases page and build your Docker container using that.

https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/releases/latest